# json_decode() in PHP not showing true or false statements

Tags: php, json

I have a response coming back that is JSON encoded, but when I decode it I lose the `true`/`false` attributes after using `$var = json_decode($response);`.

Here’s an example:

```
{
  "domain": "my.domain.com",
  "created_at": "2014-11-15 00:26:53.74059",
  "valid_mx": true
}
```

I’ve even tried:

```
$var = json_decode($response, true);
```

But it still seems to drop the `true`/`false`. How can I properly pull the `true`/`false` from the response? What am I missing?

Comment: What do you want? An array or an object or what? This works fine for me

Comment: doesn't matter, just trying to validate based on the valid_mx response. Either way it seems to drop the true/false

Comment: How are you checking the values? `print_r()`?

Comment: yes the print_r shows true/false but attempting to dig it out - it seems to drop it.

Comment: Huh that's weird. `print_r`  doesn't show true/false. [It shows blank/1](http://codepad.org/UBb8urGN).

Comment: can u enclose  true in " (double quotes)  and is it working?

Comment: "But it still seems to drop the true/false" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work for you:

(With this you have the JSON string as an array)

```
<?php

    $response = '{
                "domain": "my.domain.com",
                "created_at": "2014-11-15 00:26:53.74059",
                "valid_mx": true
            }';

    $var = json_decode($response, true);    

    if($var["valid_mx"] === TRUE)
        echo "true";
    else
        echo "false";

?>
```

Output:

```
yes
```

If you want an object just change this line:

```
$var = json_decode($response, true);
```

to this:

```
$var = json_decode($response);
```

And then you can access it with this line:

```
if($var->valid_mx === TRUE)
```

Comment: That works - I was trying to pull out the actual 'true/false' response but didn't think to actually check to see if it was set. Thanks

Comment: For clarity, the value is "set" regardless of whether it is `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Rizier123 Sure, but I wasn't questioning your answer. I was just clarifying that the value is set either way, in response to MrTechie's comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is with `print_r`, not `json_decode`.

`print_r` does not show `true` / `false` for true / false. Instead, it shows `1` / `(blank)`.

You can use `var_dump($var);` or `var_export($var);` instead which will show you the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
if(json_decode($response)->valid_max){
   //your stuff
}
```

Comment: Also if it isn't set it should be taken as false

Answer (score -2):

Just put the true in a quote and it will be working fine.

```
<?php
$response = '{
                "domain": "my.domain.com",
                "created_at": "2014-11-15 00:26:53.74059",
                "valid_mx": "true"
      }';

$var = json_decode($response, true); 
echo $var["valid_mx"]; // it will print true   
?>
```

Comment: `"true"` does not have anything to do with JSON booleans, it's just an arbitrary text that you, as human, may decide to arbitrarily map as logical value, just as you could do with `"on"`, `"yes"`, `"OK"` or `"Verdadero"`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).